# Firebird connection through Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, firebird

I was watching [tutorial](https://www.ibprovider.com/eng/documentation/connection_to_firebird_in_visual_studio_2017_via_ddex_provider.html#p2_install) about connecting Visual Studio with Firebird database server.
[image]

But the next step is the problem. I can't find Provider for Firebird:
[image]
Any suggestions?

Comment: IB Provider is commercial enterprise, what does their customer support say when you contact them ? Did you install their provider, purchased or trial ?

Comment: The tutorial you link says "Initial conditions - On the computer must be installed: Visual Studio 2017 AND IBProvider v3 [32bit]" - did you install them both? Then you would see this option: https://www.ibprovider.com/site-data/m01/eng/i/documentation/firebird_vs2017_ddex2-2/vs_add_connection.png and then your tutorial explicitly says: *If you see an empty list with OLE DB providers, this means incorrect installation of the ADO.NET provider.  (details followed)*

Comment: Already contacted their support, so it is not free for commercial purposes. I quit this idea. thank you anyway.

Comment: Exactly because for commercial purposes that is a viable option to consider. Notice, you will pay both ways, either with your (and your nervous customers!) time spent at debugging opensource libraries yourself, or with share of your money and time waiting for commercial support. It will cost you both ways, it is your choice to assess which payment is preferrable. Maybe even shipping with both libraries and make final choice later after getting some volume of feedbacks, dunno.

Comment: https://www.tabsoverspaces.com/233604-installing-ddex-provider-for-firebird-into-visual-studio-2017